# Using pprint and skipping the types name

Tags: python, printing, pprint

I want to use `pprint` for printing some complex lists, see the example below:

```
>>> x = [OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'clci-2'), (u'R', u'1691')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'dallas-pcc-1'), (u'R', u'5498')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'gx-1'), (u'R', u'2275')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'gx-2'), (u'R', u'0')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'ocs-1'), (u'R', u'31735')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'ocs-2'), (u'R', u'0')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'pcc-gx-1'), (u'R', u'46351')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rgx-1'), (u'R', u'907')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rgx-2'), (u'R', u'1010')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rocs-1'), (u'R', u'915')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rocs-2'), (u'R', u'1033')])]
>>> pprint.pprint(x)
[OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'clci-2'), (u'R', u'1691')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'dallas-pcc-1'), (u'R', u'5498')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'gx-1'), (u'R', u'2275')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'gx-2'), (u'R', u'0')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'ocs-1'), (u'R', u'31735')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'ocs-2'), (u'R', u'0')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'pcc-gx-1'), (u'R', u'46351')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rgx-1'), (u'R', u'907')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rgx-2'), (u'R', u'1010')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rocs-1'), (u'R', u'915')]),
 OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rocs-2'), (u'R', u'1033')])]
```

This is fine, except that I want to remove all type name(`OrderedDict & u`) and all unnecessary `[]`. **Is it possible with pprint?**

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @jamylak I just need to print data-structures such as above, and skipping types and [] is a great way of making the output smaller!

Comment: How about `json.dumps`?

Comment: @Boldewyn much better idea, submit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to create your own subclass of the [`pprint.PrettyPrinter` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter), and override the `.format()` method:

```
from pprint import PrettyPrinter, _recursion

class MyPrettyPrinter(PrettyPrinter):
    def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
        if isinstance(object, OrderedDict):
            if not object:
                return "()", True, False

            objid = id(object)
            if maxlevels and level >= maxlevels:
                return "(...)", False, objid in context
            if objid in context:
                return _recursion(object), False, True
            context[objid] = 1
            readable = True
            recursive = False
            components = []
            append = components.append
            level += 1
            selfformat = self.format
            for k, v in sorted(object.items()):
                krepr, kreadable, krecur = selfformat(k, context, maxlevels, level)
                vrepr, vreadable, vrecur = selfformat(v, context, maxlevels, level)
                append('({}, {})'.format(krepr, vrepr))
                readable = readable and kreadable and vreadable
                if krecur or vrecur:
                    recursive = True
            del context[objid]
            return '({})'.format(', '.join(components)), readable, recursive

        formatted, readable, recursion = PrettyPrinter.format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
        if isinstance(object, unicode):
            formatted = formatted.lstrip('u')

        return formatted, readable, recursion
```

We let the base class do most of the work and only format the `OrderedDict` explicitly; it has a custom `__repr__` which means that the original `pprint` implementation just uses that instead of recursing over it.

Then use this class instead of direct calls to `pprint.pprint()`:

```
mypprint = MyPrettyPrinter()

mypprint.pprint(x)
```

This produces:

```
>>> mypprint = MyPrettyPrinter()
>>> mypprint.pprint(x)
[(('D-ID', 'clci-2'), ('R', '1691')),
 (('D-ID', 'dallas-pcc-1'), ('R', '5498')),
 (('D-ID', 'gx-1'), ('R', '2275')),
 (('D-ID', 'gx-2'), ('R', '0')),
 (('D-ID', 'ocs-1'), ('R', '31735')),
 (('D-ID', 'ocs-2'), ('R', '0')),
 (('D-ID', 'pcc-gx-1'), ('R', '46351')),
 (('D-ID', 'rgx-1'), ('R', '907')),
 (('D-ID', 'rgx-2'), ('R', '1010')),
 (('D-ID', 'rocs-1'), ('R', '915')),
 (('D-ID', 'rocs-2'), ('R', '1033'))]
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I don't think this'll pick up "internal" unicode strings, as shown by your output.

Comment: @DSM: Urm, it didn't recurse. Curses, so we need to recurse ourselves, updating.

Comment: @DSM: Better; because of the custom `__repr__` pprint would just use that instead of recursing over it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> x = [OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'clci-2'), (u'R', u'1691')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'dallas-pcc-1'), (u'R', u'5498')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'gx-1'), (u'R', u'2275')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'gx-2'), (u'R', u'0')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'ocs-1'), (u'R', u'31735')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'ocs-2'), (u'R', u'0')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'pcc-gx-1'), (u'R', u'46351')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rgx-1'), (u'R', u'907')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rgx-2'), (u'R', u'1010')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rocs-1'), (u'R', u'915')]), OrderedDict([(u'D-ID', u'rocs-2'), (u'R', u'1033')])]
>>> print pprint.pformat(x).replace("OrderedDict([", "(") \
                           .replace("u'", "'") \
                           .replace("])", ")")

[(('D-ID', 'clci-2'), ('R', '1691')),
 (('D-ID', 'dallas-pcc-1'), ('R', '5498')),
 (('D-ID', 'gx-1'), ('R', '2275')),
 (('D-ID', 'gx-2'), ('R', '0')),
 (('D-ID', 'ocs-1'), ('R', '31735')),
 (('D-ID', 'ocs-2'), ('R', '0')),
 (('D-ID', 'pcc-gx-1'), ('R', '46351')),
 (('D-ID', 'rgx-1'), ('R', '907')),
 (('D-ID', 'rgx-2'), ('R', '1010')),
 (('D-ID', 'rocs-1'), ('R', '915')),
 (('D-ID', 'rocs-2'), ('R', '1033'))]
```

Adjust the `replace`s to your needs, I think this looks clean enough

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for printing some `dict` and `list` stuff (or stuff from classes inheriting from them), you would be better off using some other serialization, e.g., JSON:

```
import json
print json.dumps(obj)
```

Comment: With `indent=0` for new lines

Comment: I have used json.dumps for other dicts, the output is unfortunately uglier than pprint.